# How to get page argument of hook_menu as a parameter in a form generated by ajax url request?

Tags: ajax

I have an url : `abc/def/1/add`. This url has some elements:
**title
blah
blah blah**

When I click "**title**", an **ajax request** gets generated which opens a form in dialog box.This hit is on another url. I want above page id to get used in a form generated by ajax request.How can I do this. Basically I am trying to run update query on each ajax submit form request.But when I update, instead of updating single record, all records of that column gets same value which I changed.

[image]

Comment: Why not just stash the value in the `$form` array and pick it up from there?

Comment: @Clive can you please explain it a little more?

Comment: Add `$form['#foo'] = arg(2);` in the form builder/alter function, and use the same to retrieve it in the AJAX callback (`$arg = $form['#foo'];`). That way you're not consulting the URL at all in the AJAX callback, but you have the necessary context to work with

Comment: If I do {$form['#foo'] = arg(2);} , it will give me "ajax" has an argument not that "page id", which is 1, because ajax submit callback url is abc/def/%ctools_js not abc/def/1/add

Comment: No, in the form _build_ function, not in the AJAX callback.